# Response with status 200 in Asp.net and Content-Length 0

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, iis

I set up an ASP.NET project at IIS Local Server and entered a .aspx page that caused a problem that the design did not applied.

[image: IIS Settings Screen]

Aspx file header(HTML head tag) includes ascx control(CommonHeader.ascx)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=this.GetResourceUrl("js/Common/jquery-3.2.1.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=this.GetResourceUrl("js/Common/vue.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=this.GetResourceUrl("js/Common/bootstrap.js")%>"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=this.GetResourceUrl("css/bootstrap.min.css")%>"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=this.GetResourceUrl("css/bootstrap-theme.min.css")%>"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=this.GetResourceUrl("css/dashboard.css")%>"/>
```

GetResourceUrl code

```
public string GetResourceUrl(string url)
{
    string resultUrl = "";

    if (Regex.IsMatch(url, @"http[s]?:\/\/.*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace))
    {
        return url;
    }

    // When sub application url passed(like 'BoardResource/Bla/Test.js') 
    if (!url.StartsWith("/"))
    {
        resultUrl = _resourceUrl + "/";
    }

    resultUrl += url;

    return resultUrl;
}
```

BoardResources contains JavaScript and css files. When I entered the aspx page, I tried to load the resources (such as .js, .css) in the BoardResource, but only loaded css file.(The aspx file is loaded normally)

So I changed the ID of the IIS application pool to which the site belongs to LocalSystem. I set the connection account as an administrator account in the IIS site default settings.

Now I get javascript files. However, the Content-Length of the response header found in the Debug window is still 0 and the source code is not visible at all. What is the problem?

[image: Content Length 0 Picture]

Comment: Is there a problem with mime type mappings on the server, perhaps? Does it work if you deploy it to a different IIS server? Also check the permissions on the deployed files.

Comment: Check full URL in Dev tools to CSS and JS files. Are they equal?

Comment: @Vladimir Yes. I requested 'blabla.mysite.com/BoardResources/js/Common/jquery-3.2.1.js'. but still didn't work.

Comment: A stupid question, but... Are the *deployed* JS files non-empty? :) Do they have content?

Comment: @Vladimir Absolutely right. All files are not empty.
I deployed the resource project separately from the web project, and proceeded with the resource file in the web project, but the result was the same. I noticed that files could not loaded .css and .js on the site itself. Maybe I think I should take a look at the server side.

Comment: I added the Mime-Type-related configuration to Web.config and checked IIS authentication. Deployed IIS folder permissions are occupied by the Authenticated Users, SYSTEM, Administrators, and Users and are readable and writable. Is there anything else I need to check?

Comment: @ADyson I deployed it on a different server and now it works fine. Perhaps that's a problem with the server itself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue today and it is resolved after I configured IIS to handle static content from "Turn Windows Features On or Off", enabled Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP Features -> Static Content"